# exec sidekiq log on heroku

Tags: heroku, sidekiq

I want to exec the sidekiq log file on my heroku environment but I cannot find anything in the documentation nor google helps me here. I am sure it has to be sth like `exec sidekiq -L log/sidekiq.log`but that command fails on heroku.
How can I access my sidekiq log file on a heroku environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I grabbed the worker logger on heroku

```
heroku logs -t -a eventbaxx-production | grep worker.1
```

so I could see sidekiq activity.

Comment: would it work if we use `ActiveJob` instead of sidekiq's `Worker`?

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way would be

`heroku logs --tail --app app_name --dyno worker`

This will only show worker logs.