# Rails, Sidekiq, Redis on Heroku - something wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sidekiq

I have a problem with my Rails app.

App based on Ruby on Rails with Sidekiq, Redis and deployed on Heroku.
I don't know why my worker doesn't work on Heroku. I think something is wrong in my settings.

**config/initializers/sidekiq.rb**

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
  schedule_file = "config/sidekiq.yml"
  if File.exists?(schedule_file)
    Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
end
```

**workers/my_worker.rb**

```
class MyWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    ......
  end
end
```

**config/sidekiq.yml**

```
my_photos:
  cron: "30 3 */2 * *"
  class: "MyWorker"
  queue: default
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production
```

**application.rb** includes line:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

I have installed **Redis To Go** on Heroku.

**Heroku config:**

```
REDISTOGO_URL: redis://redistogo:2085d9ff......
REDIS_PROVIDER: REDISTOGO_URL
.
.
.
```

Everything works fine on localhost development and production mode (worker too) but on Heroku worker doesn't work well.

Some errors:

> Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

**heroku ps** in console displays:

```
=== web (Free): bundle exec rails server -p $PORT (1)
web.1: up 2019/09/18 16:57:03 +0200

=== worker (Free): bundle exec sidekiq -e production (1)
worker.1: crashed 2019/09/18 17:27:42 +0200
```

Yes, I restarted Heroku.

*******

**Heroku logs after change config.redis to ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] in sidekiq.rb**

```
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621771+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621789+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production
2019-09-18T16:29:30.62179+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621791+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621792+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.1-p33), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621793+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621796+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621797+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:42164
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621798+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2019-09-18T16:29:30.621799+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:30.621672 #4]  INFO -- : [2fa14d58-5519-456e-a527-9cf4ed462e86] Started GET "/dogs" for 195.136.56.0 at 2019-09-18 16:29:30 +0000
2019-09-18T16:29:30.62264+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:30.622583 #4]  INFO -- : [2fa14d58-5519-456e-a527-9cf4ed462e86] Processing by DogsController#index as HTML
2019-09-18T16:29:30.683193+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:30.683061 #4] DEBUG -- : [2fa14d58-5519-456e-a527-9cf4ed462e86]   User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-18T16:29:30.704369+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:30.704248 #4]  INFO -- : [2fa14d58-5519-456e-a527-9cf4ed462e86]   Rendering dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-18T16:29:30.708316+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:30.708230 #4] DEBUG -- : [2fa14d58-5519-456e-a527-9cf4ed462e86]   Dog Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "dogs".* FROM "dogs" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 24], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-18T16:29:30.715597+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:30.715534 #4]  INFO -- : [2fa14d58-5519-456e-a527-9cf4ed462e86]   Rendered dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:30.718909+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:30.718852 #4]  INFO -- : [2fa14d58-5519-456e-a527-9cf4ed462e86] Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 13.8ms | ActiveRecord: 28.1ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:32.200757+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myappaddress.herokuapp.com request_id=77ecb62d-e044-4eee-be8c-a0f0749af788 fwd="195.136.56.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2019-09-18T16:29:32.047254+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:32.047168 #4]  INFO -- : [2bfdeee1-c974-4a9e-97ac-659f58d14a0d] Started GET "/dogs" for 195.136.56.0 at 2019-09-18 16:29:32 +0000
2019-09-18T16:29:32.047891+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:32.047835 #4]  INFO -- : [2bfdeee1-c974-4a9e-97ac-659f58d14a0d] Processing by DogsController#index as HTML
2019-09-18T16:29:32.051783+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:32.051719 #4] DEBUG -- : [2bfdeee1-c974-4a9e-97ac-659f58d14a0d]   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-18T16:29:32.053487+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:32.053403 #4]  INFO -- : [2bfdeee1-c974-4a9e-97ac-659f58d14a0d]   Rendering dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-18T16:29:32.054812+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:32.054749 #4] DEBUG -- : [2bfdeee1-c974-4a9e-97ac-659f58d14a0d]   Dog Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "dogs".* FROM "dogs" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 24], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-18T16:29:32.055346+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:32.055289 #4]  INFO -- : [2bfdeee1-c974-4a9e-97ac-659f58d14a0d]   Rendered dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:32.056958+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:32.056901 #4]  INFO -- : [2bfdeee1-c974-4a9e-97ac-659f58d14a0d] Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 2.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:32.059156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dogs" host=myappaddress.herokuapp.com request_id=2bfdeee1-c974-4a9e-97ac-659f58d14a0d fwd="195.136.56.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=2828 protocol=https
2019-09-18T16:29:33.373311+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dogs" host=myappaddress.herokuapp.com request_id=953acff7-12c6-4876-99eb-57686a8e054b fwd="195.136.56.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=2850 protocol=https
2019-09-18T16:29:33.360115+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:33.360015 #4]  INFO -- : [953acff7-12c6-4876-99eb-57686a8e054b] Started GET "/dogs" for 195.136.56.0 at 2019-09-18 16:29:33 +0000
2019-09-18T16:29:33.360839+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:33.360763 #4]  INFO -- : [953acff7-12c6-4876-99eb-57686a8e054b] Processing by DogsController#index as HTML
2019-09-18T16:29:33.364996+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:33.364927 #4] DEBUG -- : [953acff7-12c6-4876-99eb-57686a8e054b]   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-18T16:29:33.36734+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:33.367264 #4]  INFO -- : [953acff7-12c6-4876-99eb-57686a8e054b]   Rendering dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-18T16:29:33.368712+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:33.368637 #4] DEBUG -- : [953acff7-12c6-4876-99eb-57686a8e054b]   Dog Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "dogs".* FROM "dogs" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 24], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-18T16:29:33.370049+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:33.369947 #4]  INFO -- : [953acff7-12c6-4876-99eb-57686a8e054b]   Rendered dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:33.371552+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:33.371479 #4]  INFO -- : [953acff7-12c6-4876-99eb-57686a8e054b] Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 2.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:33.506177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myappaddress.herokuapp.com request_id=11c98ea8-5df1-4a9f-9a5a-fb609bf1f9b1 fwd="195.136.56.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2019-09-18T16:29:37.398927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.146423817.b27d01ed-7668-4c8c-9451-68f3c0f447c7 sample#memory_total=143.53MB sample#memory_rss=104.20MB sample#memory_cache=39.34MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=51710pages sample#memory_pgpgout=14966pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2019-09-18T16:29:54.267638+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bin/rails console` by user myemail@o2.pl
2019-09-18T16:29:55.487272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dogs" host=myappaddress.herokuapp.com request_id=4318929d-efc2-4ad1-ad0d-c0a9ae155a8c fwd="195.136.56.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=2840 protocol=https
2019-09-18T16:29:55.474089+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:55.473957 #4]  INFO -- : [4318929d-efc2-4ad1-ad0d-c0a9ae155a8c] Started GET "/dogs" for 195.136.56.0 at 2019-09-18 16:29:55 +0000
2019-09-18T16:29:55.475425+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:55.475356 #4]  INFO -- : [4318929d-efc2-4ad1-ad0d-c0a9ae155a8c] Processing by DogsController#index as HTML
2019-09-18T16:29:55.478716+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:55.478637 #4] DEBUG -- : [4318929d-efc2-4ad1-ad0d-c0a9ae155a8c]   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-18T16:29:55.480624+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:55.480549 #4]  INFO -- : [4318929d-efc2-4ad1-ad0d-c0a9ae155a8c]   Rendering dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-18T16:29:55.481962+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:55.481884 #4] DEBUG -- : [4318929d-efc2-4ad1-ad0d-c0a9ae155a8c]   Dog Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "dogs".* FROM "dogs" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 24], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-18T16:29:55.483895+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:55.483823 #4]  INFO -- : [4318929d-efc2-4ad1-ad0d-c0a9ae155a8c]   Rendered dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:55.484818+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:55.484747 #4]  INFO -- : [4318929d-efc2-4ad1-ad0d-c0a9ae155a8c] Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 3.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:55.629132+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myappaddress.herokuapp.com request_id=d2dc2b32-bf0c-42b0-b0ee-e688014a1858 fwd="195.136.56.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2019-09-18T16:29:56.6973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dogs" host=myappaddress.herokuapp.com request_id=22b98e70-0f07-4ac8-a93e-ba2d0df3ccbf fwd="195.136.56.0" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=2850 protocol=https
2019-09-18T16:29:56.832815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myappaddress.herokuapp.com request_id=d76015da-381e-422d-8cfa-60d277ead4b8 fwd="195.136.56.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2019-09-18T16:29:56.683482+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:56.683384 #4]  INFO -- : [22b98e70-0f07-4ac8-a93e-ba2d0df3ccbf] Started GET "/dogs" for 195.136.56.0 at 2019-09-18 16:29:56 +0000
2019-09-18T16:29:56.684878+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:56.684813 #4]  INFO -- : [22b98e70-0f07-4ac8-a93e-ba2d0df3ccbf] Processing by DogsController#index as HTML
2019-09-18T16:29:56.688315+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:56.688210 #4] DEBUG -- : [22b98e70-0f07-4ac8-a93e-ba2d0df3ccbf]   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-18T16:29:56.690898+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:56.690833 #4]  INFO -- : [22b98e70-0f07-4ac8-a93e-ba2d0df3ccbf]   Rendering dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-09-18T16:29:56.692612+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:56.692550 #4] DEBUG -- : [22b98e70-0f07-4ac8-a93e-ba2d0df3ccbf]   Dog Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "dogs".* FROM "dogs" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 24], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2019-09-18T16:29:56.693963+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:56.693898 #4]  INFO -- : [22b98e70-0f07-4ac8-a93e-ba2d0df3ccbf]   Rendered dogs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.9ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:56.695684+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:56.695620 #4]  INFO -- : [22b98e70-0f07-4ac8-a93e-ba2d0df3ccbf] Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
2019-09-18T16:29:58.295567+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:58.295456 #4]  INFO -- : [98a19c4a-cdda-4112-bb38-5869ede78b49] Started GET "/dogs" for 195.136.56.0 at 2019-09-18 16:29:58 +0000
2019-09-18T16:29:58.297473+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-09-18T16:29:58.297393 #4]  INFO -- : [98a19c4a-cdda-4112-bb38-5869ede78b49] Processing by DogsController#index as HTML
2019-09-18T16:29:58.301213+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-09-18T16:29:58.301128 #4] DEBUG -- : [98a19c4a-cdda-4112-bb38-5869ede78b49]   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-09-18T18:45:05.749467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.146423817.2c282eb9-e271-478a-a164-ab1ee7b48d15 sample#load_avg_1m=0.35
2019-09-18T18:45:05.779083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.146423817.2c282eb9-e271-478a-a164-ab1ee7b48d15 sample#memory_total=141.63MB sample#memory_rss=102.39MB sample#memory_cache=39.24MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=51236pages sample#memory_pgpgout=14978pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
```

**Sidekiq logs:**

```
2019-09-18T21:42:34.875Z pid=2604 tid=gmvw62cjk class=FlickrWorker jid=d4d37c3accf6190b8193758d elapsed=5.561 INFO: fail
2019-09-18T21:42:34.875Z pid=2604 tid=gmvw62cjk WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"queue":"default","args":[],"class":"FlickrWorker","retry":true,"jid":"d4d37c3accf6190b8193758d","created_at":1568805601.6104372,"enqueued_at":1568842949.307712,"error_message":"could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use","error_class":"ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError","failed_at":1568805607.190152,"retry_count":5,"retried_at":1568806408.705434},"jobstr":"{\"queue\":\"default\",\"args\":[],\"class\":\"FlickrWorker\",\"retry\":true,\"jid\":\"d4d37c3accf6190b8193758d\",\"created_at\":1568805601.6104372,\"enqueued_at\":1568842949.307712,\"error_message\":\"could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use\",\"error_class\":\"ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError\",\"failed_at\":1568805607.190152,\"retry_count\":5,\"retried_at\":1568806408.705434}"}
2019-09-18T21:42:34.875Z pid=2604 tid=gmvw62cjk WARN: ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
2019-09-18T21:42:34.875Z pid=2604 tid=gmvw62cjk WARN: /home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:201:in `block in wait_poll'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `loop'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `wait_poll'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:151:in `internal_poll'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:277:in `internal_poll'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:145:in `block in poll'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:155:in `synchronize'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:145:in `poll'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:799:in `acquire_connection'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:523:in `checkout'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in `connection'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1014:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:196:in `block in pluck'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:584:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:196:in `pluck'
/home/miro/ror/my-app/app/workers/flickr_worker.rb:11:in `block in perform'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/flickraw-0.9.10/lib/flickraw/response.rb:42:in `block in each'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/flickraw-0.9.10/lib/flickraw/response.rb:42:in `each'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/flickraw-0.9.10/lib/flickraw/response.rb:42:in `each'
/home/miro/ror/my-app/app/workers/flickr_worker.rb:11:in `reject'
/home/miro/ror/my-app/app/workers/flickr_worker.rb:11:in `perform'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:193:in `execute_job'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:134:in `invoke'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:160:in `block in process'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:133:in `block (6 levels) in dispatch'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:107:in `local'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:43:in `block in call'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:42:in `call'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:128:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:254:in `stats'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:123:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:13:in `call'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:122:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:75:in `global'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:121:in `block in dispatch'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/logger.rb:16:in `with_context'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:27:in `with_job_hash_context'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:120:in `dispatch'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:159:in `process'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:78:in `process_one'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in `watchdog'
/home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:26:in `block in safe_thread'
2019-09-18T21:42:34.876Z pid=2604 tid=ov922z8j8 class=FlickrWorker jid=73817a6886c934cc0e57d83c INFO: start
2019-09-18T21:42:34.907Z pid=2604 tid=gmvw62ctw class=FlickrWorker jid=f7a4c1d1e5da2939db1202ae elapsed=5.591 INFO: fail
2019-09-18T21:42:34.907Z pid=2604 tid=gmvw62ctw WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"queue":"default","args":[],"class":"FlickrWorker","retry":true,"jid":"f7a4c1d1e5da2939db1202ae","created_at":1568806211.883125,"enqueued_at":1568842949.3102987,"error_message":"could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use","error_class":"ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError","failed_at":1568806217.393686,"retry_count":5,"retried_at":1568806883.9672208},"jobstr":"{\"queue\":\"default\",\"args\":[],\"class\":\"FlickrWorker\",\"retry\":true,\"jid\":\"f7a4c1d1e5da2939db1202ae\",\"created_at\":1568806211.883125,\"enqueued_at\":1568842949.3102987,\"error_message\":\"could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use\",\"error_class\":\"ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError\",\"failed_at\":1568806217.393686,\"retry_count\":5,\"retried_at\":1568806883.9672208}"}
2019-09-18T21:42:34.907Z pid=2604 tid=gmvw62ctw WARN: ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
2019-09-18T21:42:34.908Z pid=2604 tid=gmvw62ctw WARN: /home/miro/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:201:in `block in wait_poll'
```

**heroku logs | grep worker**

```
2019-09-18T17:31:17.211968+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec sidekiq -e production`
2019-09-18T17:31:17.859475+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-09-18T17:31:21.738484+00:00 app[worker.1]: pid=4 tid=gq4np076o INFO: Booting Sidekiq 6.0.0 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redistogo:REDACTED@porgy.redistogo.com:11228/", :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-4"}
2019-09-18T17:31:21.766614+00:00 app[worker.1]: pid=4 tid=gq4np076o INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: flickr_photos
2019-09-18T17:31:23.288563+00:00 app[worker.1]: pid=4 tid=gq4np076o INFO: Running in ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-linux]
2019-09-18T17:31:23.288599+00:00 app[worker.1]: pid=4 tid=gq4np076o INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2019-09-18T17:31:23.288602+00:00 app[worker.1]: pid=4 tid=gq4np076o INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289887+00:00 app[worker.1]: You are using Redis v3.2.12, Sidekiq requires Redis v4.0.0 or greater
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289931+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:59:in `run'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289932+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.0/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289933+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289934+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<top (required)>'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289935+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289936+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289937+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289938+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:465:in `exec'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289939+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.28994+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289941+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289943+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289943+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289944+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289945+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289946+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289947+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289948+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.289949+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
2019-09-18T17:31:23.357667+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-09-18T17:31:23.411452+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Answer (score 19):

John is correct, Sidekiq 6 requires at least Redis 4, but Redis To Go has not updated from version 3.

Instead of downgrading to meet the requirements of Redis To Go i would recommended moving dependencies.

Since you are using Heroku, [two popular alternatives](https://stackshare.io/stackups/heroku-redis-vs-redis-cloud-vs-redis-to-go) are [Heroku Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) and [Redis Cloud](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud).

Since Redis 4 was released 2.5 years ago and Redis 5 is already released, its safe to say that Redis To Go is falling behind and you should strongly consider moving to a dependency that gets updated more frequently.

Neglecting to do so will be more difficult in the long run.

Comment: should probably be accepted answer, it fixed the issue for me
it's also worth pointing out that the config values `REDISTOGO_URL` and `REDIS_PROVIDER` can be unset in this case

Answer (score 9):

Seems to be a versioning issue:

Sidekiq 6 requires Redis 4, but RedisToGo as provided by Heroku is still using Redis 3.x
I stepped around the problem by specifying in my Gemfile:

`gem 'sidekiq', '5.2.7'`

Answer (score 2):

You have your redis URL hardcoded in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`

Instead of:

```
config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
```

use

```
config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
```

and ensure `REDIS_URL` set correctly on heroku (maybe set it manually or maybe the add-on or heroku takes care of it, I don't remember).

Comment: I changed it to ENV['REDIS_URL'] and ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] but still not working. Why Heroku still displays: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)?

Comment: `localhost:6379` is hardcoded in two places in your `sidekiq.rb`. Did you change them both?

Comment: @AdamMcCrea Yes :) in configure_server and configure_client

Comment: please, attach the full stacktrace

Comment: @mrzasa Just added above :)

Comment: I'd rather need the part of the logs that contain the stacktrace of the redis error. Most probably the sidekiq logs.

Comment: OK, I just added sidekiq logs too. From localhost, because I don't know how to look into sidekiq logs on heroku.

Comment: On localhost - you can't connect to the DB, becasue you don't have connections in pool, you need to increase it (a topic for another question). In heroku without logs it's hard to say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969031/exec-sidekiq-log-on-heroku https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3267

Comment: @mrzasa Thanks for the link. I just added heroku logs for worker. Hmm it looks like problem with Redis version...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like so.

Comment: I installed redis 4.1.3 (was 4.1.2) but on Heroku still is the same log with version of Redis.

Comment: Where did you installed it? It seems that your provider have outdated redis

Comment: Hmm, I installed it on localhost and I pushed updated Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to Heroku.

Comment: Check redis DB version in  redis to go.

Comment: When I click on Redis To Go link on Heroku I see only: Version 3.2.12.

Comment: Yeah, it's default for them: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo#redis-3-2. Either contact them to get a newer version, or change the provider.

Comment: Thanks for help, I sent an email to them :)

Comment: You're welcome :). Upvote & accept would be nice in exchange of that :).

Comment: Redis To Go answeared me that they can't upgrade Redis version to >=4 at this moment, because they use v3 :)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you come up with a solution?